# Why tor2web is not secure?

Tags: configuration, proxy

I want to ask about tor2web proxy which is used to access the onion sites through normal internet browser, Why it is said that it is not secure when it uses HTTPS to fetch the onion site from the Tor network. 
For example https://duskgytldkxiuqc6.onion.to/

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post source that is saying "that it is not secure". This would help frame the answer in context of your question and add specificity.

Answer (score 3):

You're given a fairly good set of protections in the Tor network: three layers of encrypted misdirection, plus a browser that blocks many tracking features. Using a service like Tor 2 Web or Onion Cab not only removes the browser-based protections, but also lets anyone listening to the network (or the proxy server admin) see what pages you're connecting to. The point of Tor is that users can connect without being eavesdropped on, and going through the clearnet, even with https, seriously cripples the efforts made to protect users.

Answer (score 0):

The point of tor is to not stand out when on the tor network, that is what being anonymous us about. When you use a different browser your browser fingerprint is much more unique. That means you stand out when compared to everyone else using the same identical tor browser with the same extensions. If you just want to connect you are probably fine, but I wouldn't do it on a computer that is connected to your home network to mitigate the risk of anything being compromised.

Comment: I believe OP is asking about security of tor2web in light of https use in the proxy (onion.to). OP also doesn't clarify source of who is saying that it is not secure. So I dont see how your answer, while informative on browser fingerprinting, is relevant to the question.

Comment: So tor2web was originally made so someone could publish materials to tor. It is not really for viewing .onion sites. The security issue is that the tor2web proxy is in a privileged spot to monitor or capture the sites you are visiting. There is also the risk of javascript injection that could inject trackers or malware. In your non-tor browser, if any extensions have the ability to monitor traffic like ad-blockers, could leak the onion domains you visit.Your DNS could leak if not configured, then you would be leaking the domains that you are visiting (possibly to your ISP).